# What does "AlwaysOff DEP is not enabled for any processes" mean?

Tags: windows

Having run a powershell script to help determine whether DEP is enabled, I get the output `AlwaysOff DEP is not enabled for any processes`. What does this mean exactly? Does it mean that DEP is disabled?

Comment: Yes it does....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It means that DEP is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try method 1 [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912923) and see what the three WMI queries return. If `wmic OS Get DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy` returns 0, then, like @joeqwerty said and this [KB article confirms](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875352), DEP is not enabled.